# Installer Language Resource not generated C#

Tags: c#, windows-installer, resx

I have an installer for a Winforms application. When I run the solution in Visual Studio, this kind of files are generated `*.resources.dll`. The problem is they are not generated with the installer. Resx files output is copy always, and build option embedded resource.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Installer projects?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul yes I am